# Identify the Mobile Platform in which webapp is build

Tags: web-applications, jquery-mobile, frameworks, platform

I am constantly building web-apps in **Jquery Mobile**... I have also customized their theme and layout as far the client requirements... But i have seen some interesting stuff on net while finding something new to my layout...

[View This Webapp on mobile](http://lucknowjobs.net/jobs/)

Obviously, its not JqMobile because jqMobile doesn't provide this type of functionality i think... Then what is it, **Sencha Touch or any other mobile platform**...

1. How can i build a webapp like this as a default theme on this webapp
   and also with some basic functionality like it???
2. Or is it possible to build in Jqmobile??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Its a wordpress block, and that website is using WpTouch plugin.  http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wptouch/
2. Yes, it is possible to build in jquery-mobile. but you have to tweak alot for matching it to client's requirement. Or you can build without using framework.